# android samsung galaxy 3 4.4 'internet' browser position: bug and redirect

Tags: android, css, mobile-website, android-internet

I came across a few strange bugs when browsing a website using the stock 'internet'  app browser on Android Galaxy Samsung 3 4.4.

Specifically elements that were positioned `:absolute`, for css3 animations were not positioned within their `position:relative;` defined container.. it's almost as if `position: relative` was completely omitted in this mobile browser.

So wondering **A.)** If anyone has suggestions for this bug? or **B.)** If there is away to sniff out the stock Android Galaxy S 3 4.4 '`internet`' *browser* and provide a redirect to a Chrome download (none of the above errors appear on Android Chrome) or **C.)** some sort of device specific conditional ability for this browser to add specific styles ONLY for this browser.